# Interrupts and system calls dispatching in Linux

Tags: linux, interrupt, system-calls, interrupt-handling

Are hardware interrupts and system calls/exceptions dispatched by the same dispatcher procedure in Linux? If you see Linux source, you will notice that hardware interrupts (on x86 arch) on their interrupt vectors doesn't contain more instructions that PUSH interrupt vector number on the stack and JUMP to common_interrupt.

**My question:**
Are every interrupt in Linux (exceptions (include SysCall), interrupts) dispatched by the same way until reach some point to branch? (in the reason of their type)

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 4):

> Are hardware interrupts and system calls/exceptions dispatched by the same dispatcher procedure in Linux?

No. Exceptions, system calls and hardware interrupts are dispatched in a different way. If you will look in the [arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S), you will find there all of them. First is the `idtentry` macro:

```
.macro idtentry sym do_sym has_error_code:req paranoid=0 shift_ist=-1
ENTRY(\sym)
...
...
...
END(\sym)
.endm
```

which provides preparation for an exception handling (stores registers, calls of an exception handler and etc....). Also definition of exceptions handlers with the `idtentry` macro:

```
idtentry divide_error           do_divide_error         has_error_code=0
idtentry overflow           do_overflow         has_error_code=0
idtentry bounds             do_bounds           has_error_code=0
```

Most of exceptions handlers are in the [arch/x86/kernel/trap.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/traps.c)

Entry point of hardware interrupts is `irq_entries_start`. And the system call handling is starts at the `entry_SYSCALL_64`.

> My question: Are every interrupt in Linux (exceptions (include
>   SysCall), interrupts) dispatched by the same way until reach some
>   point to branch? (in the reason of their type)

No. They are similar, but not the same. For example, system call preparation routine (`entry_SYSCALL_64`) checks the type of system call (64-bit or 32-bit emulation), has each time the same state of registers before execution (depends on ABI) and etc..., but for example an exception handler first of all check the type of exception to select correct stack from [IST](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/kernel-stacks) and etc.

More info you can find in the [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual 3A](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-system-programming-manual-325384.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How is it reached to get to point in where we are dispatching these three separately on x86? (SysCalls, exceptions, HW interrupts) If I know right, every interrupt (SysCalls already no, because of SYSENTER and SYSEXIT instruction) is on HW level directed to its vector number address.